# $\int_0^\infty \sin(x^2)~dx=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4}$

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

My attempt:

Cauchy's theorem gives $\int_0^R \sin(x^2)dx+\int_R^{Re^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}\sin(z^2) dz+\int_{Re^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}^0\sin(z^2)dz=0$

Denote $\sin(z^2)=Im(e^{iz^2})$

I consider $R\to \infty$ implies $\int_R^{Re^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}e^{iz^2} dz\to 0$ but I am not entirly sure why.

$ |\int_R^{Re^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}e^{iz^2} dz| \leq \int_R^{Re^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}|e^{iz^2}| dz $ , how to advance ?.

Now , let's suppose I show that $\int_R^{Re^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}e^{iz^2} dz\to 0$ Then , $\int_0^R \sin(x^2)dx+\int_{Re^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}^0\sin(z^2)dz=0 \implies \int_0^R e^{-x^2}dx = -\int_{Re^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}^0e^{iz^2}dz$

My problem is solving $\int_{Re^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}^0e^{iz^2}dz$.

I consider to use taylor series $e^{iz^2}=1+iz^2+E(z)$ but I am not entirely sure about it.

Any help ?

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Comment: Please do not use titles that are entirely MathJax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the straight line segment from $z=Re^{i\pi/4}$ to $z=0$ we parameterize $z$ as $z=te^{i\pi/4}$, where $t$ goes from $t=R$ to $t=0$ and $e^{iz^2}=e^{it^2e^{i\pi/2}}=e^{-t^2}$.

On the quarter circular arc, parameterize $z$ as $z=Re^{i\phi}$ where $\phi$ goes from $0$ to $\pi/4$ and $e^{iz^2}=e^{iR^2e^{i2\phi}}$.

Then, applying Cauchy's Integral Theorem leads to

$$0=\int_0^R e^{ix^2}\,dx+\int_0^{\pi/4}e^{iR^2 e^{i2\phi}}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi+\int_R^0 e^{-t^2}\,e^{i\pi/4}\,dt\tag1$$

Letting $R\to\infty$ in $(1)$ we find that

$$\int_0^\infty e^{ix^2}\,dx= e^{i\pi/4}\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}\,dt\tag2$$

Now, just set the real and imaginary parts of $(1)$ and $(2)$ equal.

---

**NOTE**:

We can show that $\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_0^{\pi/4} Re^{iR^2e^{i2\phi}}\,d\phi=0$ as follows.

$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_0^{\pi/4} Re^{iR^2e^{i2\phi}}\,d\phi\right| &\le R\int_0^{\pi/4} e^{-R^2 \sin(2\phi)}\,d\phi\\\\
&=\frac R2 \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-R^2 \sin(\phi)}\,d\phi\\\\
&\le \frac R2 \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-R^2 (2\phi/\pi)}\,d\phi\tag3
\end{align}$$

Now carry out the integral in $(3)$ and let $R\to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Do you accept non complex analysis approach? If yes, then:

1. using $x^2=t$ changing variables we get:

$$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\sin x^2dx=\frac12 \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin t}{\sqrt{t}}dt$$
knowing
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{-tu^2}du$$
immediately we have
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin t}{\sqrt{t}}dt=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\sin t \ dt\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{-tu^2}du = (!)=\\
=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}du\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{-tu^2}dt=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{du}{1+u^4}=\\=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cdot \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$
big minus of this way is, that on place $(!)$ we need long work for argue to replacing integrating order, but this is most elegant way I know.

2. So, I can suggest second way, again using only real variable.

Shortly, We can use "multiplier" $e^{-kt},k>0$, consider $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin t}{\sqrt{t}}e^{-kt}$, where, using method analogical 1-st case we more easily can approach result again replace integrating order and use limit $k\to0$ . If you would like I'll write in details this way also, but remembering possible priority of complex variable way, I stop.

Comment: I'm saying this because I didn't come up with this proof myself, I just read it and was glad to be able to bring it here for everyone to enjoy - I'm surprised it takes three weeks and 86 views and only one person liked this charm. Who are you, seeing the same beauty as me?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the hint tells you to integrate $e^{-z^2}$, not $e^{iz^2}$, then be careful and don't mistake "converges toward zero" and "equals zero" (some of your equalities are actually asymptotic equalities in the sens that their difference tends toward zero).

For the convergence of the first integral toward zero, use the fact that $|e^z| = e^{\Re(z)}$ for all $z$. In your case, you integrate $|e^{-z^2}| = e^{-\Re(z^2)}$. Since $z$ has an argument bewteen $0$ and $\pi/4$, $z^2$ has an argument bewteen $0$ and $\pi/2$, thus a non-negative real part. This should help you to conclude.

Then, $\int_0^R e^{-z^2} dz$ when $R \rightarrow +\infty$ is known and $\int_0^{Re^{i\pi/4}} e^{-z^2} dz$ = $e^{i\pi/4}\int_0^R e^{-iz^2} dz$ by a change of variable, which should allow you to conlude by looking at the real and imaginary parts of this integral (recall that $e^{i\pi/4} = (i + 1)/\sqrt{2}$).